# Troubleshooting ASHA Protocol Audio Streaming Issue: LEAP Error in CoreBluetooth BLE Connection

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, audio-streaming, core-bluetooth, packet-capture

I'm building a mac application to allow audio streaming to hearing aid devices using the [ASHA protocol](https://source.android.com/docs/core/connect/bluetooth/asha). The central is using the CoreBluetooth BLE library to open an L2CAP connection to send audio packets to the hearing aid device. It's able to discover the hearing aid device and the central is able to read/write to its characteristics with no issues. But the biggest hurdle right now is getting the audio streaming to actually work over L2CAP connection to hearing aid device.

I think I pinpointed my issue in the logs using the PacketLogger application which can be downloaded from [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/bluetooth/). Every time I connect my hearing aid device to the application, I see a LEAP Receive and LEAP Send in PacketLogger. The LEAP Send packet shows an error.

This is what I see in the decoded packet for LEAP Receive:
[LEAP Receive decoded packet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p6dPs.png)

And this is what I see for LEAP Send packet:
[LEAP Send decoded packet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mVQiS.png)

I did some research on what LEAP is, but nothing really came up in terms of BLE. Best info I came across is something called Lightweight EAP which has something to do with authentication for WLAN networks. But I don't think that applies here. Has anybody came across this issue when developing CoreBluetooth applications? If so, how did you resolve it?